# PyQt5 Gui Thread to worker Thread signal/Slot

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qthread

I am trying to make a simple communication between a worker thread, in this case it is called `WorkToDo` via the PyQt5 Signals and Slots mechanism. I can reliably send data from the Worker to the Gui thread via this mechanism, but I cannot do the same to the gui thread. From my research I have found that this is due to the fact that I have overridden the `run` function with my own logic. My question, is there any way to manually handle the execution of signals in the worker thread? Is there a better way to accomplish this?

*EDIT*:
I am actually not overriding `run` as I do not see `run` listed in the documentation for QObject. I am mistaken as this is a default function of a QThread object. This is more perplexing to me. Unless I am just further misunderstanding this.

```
import sys
import time
import qdarkstyle

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
                            QWidget, QLineEdit, QMessageBox, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QTabWidget,
                            QComboBox, QProgressBar, QApplication, QLabel, QGroupBox, QFileDialog, QTextEdit,
                            QStyleFactory, QFormLayout
                            )

from PyQt5 import (Qt, QtCore)

from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class Command:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.cmd = kwargs.get('cmd', None)
        self.args = kwargs.get('args')

class CommandSignals(QObject):
    command = pyqtSignal(Command)

class WorkToDo(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.counter = 0
        self.signals = CommandSignals()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(Command)
    def process_command(self, command):
        """
        @brief       process update from gui thread
        @param       self     self
        @param       command  command
        @return      none
        """
        print(f'Update from GUI: {command.__dict__}')
        if command.cmd == 'add_to_counter':
            self.counter = self.counter + command.args.get('addition', 0)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        """
        @brief       actual thread function to run,
                     started via thread.started signal (why its decorated with a pyqtSlot)
        @param       self  obj ref
        @return      none
        """
        while True:
            QThread.sleep(1)
            # emit text change signal to main gui thread
            cmd = Command(
                cmd = 'update_text',
                args = {
                    'text': f'Hello update {self.counter}'
                }
            )
            print(f'Update from worker: {cmd.__dict__}')
            self.signals.command.emit(cmd)
            self.counter += 1


class Gui(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        """ make gui elements """
        layout = QFormLayout()
        self.text_line = QLineEdit()
        self.add_button = QPushButton('Add 10 To Counter')
        layout.addRow(self.text_line)
        layout.addRow(self.add_button)

        self.add_button.clicked.connect(self.issue_button_update)
        self.signals = CommandSignals()
        self.MakeThreadWorker()

        """ finalize gui """
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.setWindowTitle('Sync Thread Command/Response test')
        self.show()


    def MakeThreadWorker(self):
        self.worker_thread = QThread()
        self.worker = WorkToDo()

        """ incoming gui update command, works """
        self.worker.signals.command.connect(self.process_command)
        """ outgoing update to worker thread, does not work """
        self.signals.command.connect(self.worker.process_command)

        """ signal to start the thread function, works """
        self.worker_thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)

        self.worker_thread.start()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.worker_thread)


    @pyqtSlot(Command)
    def process_command(self, command):
        """
        @brief       process update from work thread
        @param       self     self
        @param       command  command object
        @return      none
        """
        if command.cmd == 'update_text':
            text_update = command.args.get('text', '')
            self.text_line.setText(text_update)

    def issue_button_update(self):
        cmd = Command(
            cmd = 'add_to_counter',
            args = {
                'addition': 10
            }
        )
        print('Button Clicked!')
        self.signals.command.emit(cmd)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    APPLICATION = QApplication([])
    APPLICATION.setStyleSheet(qdarkstyle.load_stylesheet_pyqt5())
    gui = Gui()
    sys.exit(APPLICATION.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that with True while you are blocking the event loop of the secondary thread preventing the signals from being received, if you want to do a periodic task then use a QTimer.

```py
import sys
import time
import qdarkstyle

from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot, QObject, QThread, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFormLayout, QLineEdit, QPushButton, QWidget


class Command:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.cmd = kwargs.get("cmd", None)
        self.args = kwargs.get("args")


class CommandSignals(QObject):
    command = pyqtSignal(Command)


class WorkToDo(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.counter = 0
        self.signals = CommandSignals()
        self.timer = QTimer(self, timeout=self.run, interval=1000)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def start(self):
        self.timer.start()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def stop(self):
        self.timer.stop()

    @pyqtSlot(Command)
    def process_command(self, command):
        """
        @brief       process update from gui thread
        @param       self     self
        @param       command  command
        @return      none
        """
        print(f"Update from GUI: {command.__dict__}")
        if command.cmd == "add_to_counter":
            self.counter = self.counter + command.args.get("addition", 0)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        print(self.thread(), self.timer.thread())
        cmd = Command(cmd="update_text", args={"text": f"Hello update {self.counter}"})
        print(f"Update from worker: {cmd.__dict__}")
        self.signals.command.emit(cmd)
        self.counter += 1


class Gui(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        """ make gui elements """
        layout = QFormLayout()
        self.text_line = QLineEdit()
        self.add_button = QPushButton("Add 10 To Counter")
        layout.addRow(self.text_line)
        layout.addRow(self.add_button)

        self.add_button.clicked.connect(self.issue_button_update)
        self.signals = CommandSignals()
        self.MakeThreadWorker()

        """ finalize gui """
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.setWindowTitle("Sync Thread Command/Response test")
        self.show()

    def MakeThreadWorker(self):
        self.worker_thread = QThread()
        self.worker = WorkToDo()

        """ incoming gui update command, works """
        self.worker.signals.command.connect(self.process_command)
        """ outgoing update to worker thread, does not work """
        self.signals.command.connect(self.worker.process_command)

        """ signal to start the thread function, works """
        self.worker_thread.started.connect(self.worker.start)

        self.worker_thread.start()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.worker_thread)

    @pyqtSlot(Command)
    def process_command(self, command):
        """
        @brief       process update from work thread
        @param       self     self
        @param       command  command object
        @return      none
        """
        if command.cmd == "update_text":
            text_update = command.args.get("text", "")
            self.text_line.setText(text_update)

    def issue_button_update(self):
        cmd = Command(cmd="add_to_counter", args={"addition": 10})
        print("Button Clicked!")
        self.signals.command.emit(cmd)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    APPLICATION = QApplication([])
    APPLICATION.setStyleSheet(qdarkstyle.load_stylesheet_pyqt5())
    gui = Gui()
    sys.exit(APPLICATION.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you. This does make sense.

Comment: @eyllanesc I believe that there could be something more about this. For example, if the `pyqtSlot` decorator is removed from the `process_command` of the worker, it works as expected, and I believe that that's due to the fact that when Qt connects to the function and doesn't "find" an actual Qt slot, it uses a direct connection instead of a queued one (which prevents the signal from being received as you explained). In fact, it also works by leaving the decorator and connecting the signal using Qt.DirectConnection.

Comment: @musicamante I am going to give you a clue: analyze in which thread each function is executed with your modification.

Comment: @eyllanesc I am coming from an embedded RTOS environment mainly, is there a way to allow for a Thread priority with QThreads? My thought is allowing other threads to preempt a "WorkToDo" thread object with some obvious reworking to make the thread run code re-entrant.

Comment: @LukeGary You can set [the priority](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#setPriority) but do not expect the same behavior in an application that runs in an RTOS.